# PHP file_exists() anomaly

Tags: php, file-exists

i ran into this wierd problem: the $myImg variable has been extracted from some local html and points to a file i would like to check. With the string variable file_exists gives false, but if the content os variable is inserted manually it gives true.

`var_dump($myImg);`

outputs: `string(26) "content/images/1107_16.jpg"`

```
var_dump(file_exists($myImg));
```

outputs: `bool(false)`

```
var_dump(file_exists("content/images/1107_16.jpg"));
```

outputs: `bool(true)`

How could it happen?
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Offtopic: for checking files, I'd advise to use [`is_file()`](http://www.php.net/is_file), as [`file_exists()`](http://www.php.net/file_exists) checks both files and directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the string before passing it to file_exists method

```
$myImg = mb_convert_encoding($myImg, "UTF-8");
```

Additionally, you can always trim the other unwanted characters attached to the dirty string.

Answer (score 6):

The length of `content/images/1107_16.jpg` is not `45`, so obviously there are other characters. Try trimming the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
riad@riad-desktop:~$ php -r 'print(strlen("content/images/1107_16.jpg"));'
26
```

So, Your string is bad (maybe consist of a bad characters (\0 ?) on the end

Answer (score 1):

I offer you to compare the results using `bin2hex()`:

```
var_dump(bin2hex($myImg));
var_dump(bin2hex("content/images/1107_16.jpg"));
```

It seems that it's the problem of different charsets.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps some invisible character in your $myImg? something like a line break?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be have some unprintable characters in your string, or a different character encoding:

```
var_dump ("content/images/1107_16.jpg");
string(26) "content/images/1107_16.jpg"
```

Note that this correctly reports 26 bytes - which would be right with ASCII (or UTF-8). The 45 bytes reported above would sem like some sort of multibyte encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
string(45) "content/images/1107_16.jpg"
```

should be less chars long try :

```
trim($myImg)
```

to remove spacechars