# Php says it can't find a class which is already included

Tags: php

I am getting a `Fatal error: Class 'Hybrid_Auth' not found` When I am sure I included it like this:

```
require_once( $base_url."/includes/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );//$base_url is the domain where I am running this, currently, localhost
```

And just to be sure, I modified the class file like:

```
 echo "HAUTH Loaded";
class Hybrid_Auth 
{
    public static $version = "2.1.2";
```

And that echo did show up on the output page, right above that error. Any idea what to do?

Edit: I also tried:

```
require_once( $base_url."/includes/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );
var_dump( file_exists($base_url."/includes/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php") );die;
```

Which outputs:

```
HAUTH Loaded

boolean false
```

How come the `require` doesn't throw any error plus the `echo` in the file is executed, yet the next line suggests the file doesn't even exist?

EDIT 2: My urls are being rewritten via htaccess like `RewriteRule ^(.*) ./route.php?path=$1 [L]`, so that the URLS are clean and SEO friendly, can this be responsible for this issue?

Comment: Did you declare `Hybrid_Auth` in a namespace?

Comment: @ComFreek umm, I am just trying to install it after downloading from here: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net

Comment: Look to the line number where the error is occurring. Also, You want to get the echo in the constructor code to say hello.

Comment: Don't you create an instance before include the file?

Comment: What does `$base_url` contain? A beer says it's a `http://` address

Comment: @Pekka웃: yup, it is `http://localhost`

Comment: Make sure autoload_namespaces.php has an array entry for 'Hybrid' => $vendorDir . '/hybridauth/'

Comment: For `include()`, always use a filesystem path - it won't work with a `http://` address as a separate PHP process will start for that, parse the PHP, and return an empty result

Comment: @Pekka  but my allow_url_include is already on

Comment: Still when serving files over the http protocol it doesn't do what you think it does. @Bluemagica.

Comment: @Bluemagica Open `http://localhost/includes/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php` in your browser. How much PHP code do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `include()`ing PHP code, you must always use a filesystem path.

When using a `http://` address, as a separate PHP process will start for the resource, parse the PHP, and return an empty result instead of the PHP code that you want to include.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `var_dump(file_exists(...))` anomaly, but it may be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676295/php-file-exists-anomaly). That's not what you're trying to solve, though.

Keep namespaces in mine when you are trying to use the Hybrid_Auth class within your code. If your code has a namespace, and if Hybrid_Auth doesn't declare its own, you need to reference it with a backslash, e.g. `$auth = new \Hybrid_Auth();`.

If namespacing is not the issue, please provide further details of the code surrounding where you're trying to use Hybrid_Auth.

Comment: Why the downvote? My answer is valid, just not applicable to the OP's situation, which is now clear, but wasn't previously.